# Weaker analogues of amenability for groups of piecewise projective homeomorphisms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a subring of ${\bf R}$ and let $H(A)$ be the group defined/constructed in [Monod's 2013 PNAS paper](https://egg.epfl.ch/%7Enmonod/articles/vn.html). Monod showed that provided $A\neq {\bf Z}$, $H(A)$ is non-amenable. (The proof breaks down for $H({\bf Z})$: that group is related to the realization of Thompson's $F$ by piecewise linear homeomorphisms of [0,1], but has slightly different conditions on the breakpoints.)

In harmonic analysis and geometric group theory, there are a number of notions which are known in general to be strictly weaker than amenability, yet still have some flavour of one of the many equivalent forms of amenability. For instance: weak amenability in the sense of Cowling--Haagerup and deCanniere--Haagerup; the Haagerup property a.k.a. a-T-menability; the approximation property of Haagerup--Kraus; Property A a.k.a. exactness...

I was wondering if there have been any attempts to establish which of these properties hold or do not hold for $H(A)$, even for a single specific choice of $A$. For instance, Farley showed that $F$ acts properly on some CAT(0)-cube-complex, which implies that it has the Haagerup property; would a similar construction be possible for $H(A)$ for other choices of $A$?

Similar questions could be asked for the [Lodha-Moore groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.4250).

Comment: Property A is not known for $F$.  But $F$ is inner amenable, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05086.pdf .

Comment: I proved [publisher (CRAS) link without paywall](https://comptes-rendus.academie-sciences.fr/mathematique/articles/10.5802/crmath.155/) that $H(A)$ has no infinite subgroup with Kazhdan's Property T, for any $A$.

Comment: Haagerup Property sounds plausible, but it's still unknown, even for the whole piecewise affine subgroup. However Property PW (existence of proper action on a CAT(0) cube complex) fails in general, since it fails for $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$, see my 2015 Math Z. paper ([ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1318)).

Comment: Is it true that $H(\mathbf{Z})$ is isomorphic to Thompson's group $F$?  Monod only says that it is "related" to Thompson's group in Problem 12 of that paper.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that the Lodha--Moore groups are inner amenable, by a similar argument as for $F$, but I don't think anyone has actually written this up.

Comment: @YCor the fact that no infinite subgroup of $H(\mathbf {R})$ has property (T) also follows from the fact (written in [a paper with Juschenko Matte Bon and Monod](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04977) )  that the natural action of $H(\mathbf{R})$ on $\mathbf{R}$ is hereditarily amenable. That is, the action of every subgroup $G$ of $H(\mathbf{R})$ on every orbit preserves a mean.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Oops, I had the circle version in mind. For the interval version, it's quite immediate that $H(\mathbf{R})$ is locally indicable (every nontrivial finitely generated subgroup admits $\mathbf{Z}$ as quotient)... for the same reason, my comment claiming the failure of Property PW doesn't apply.

Comment: @CalebEckhardt Oops, you are quite right, I was going from memory. I have corrected the statement in the question.